# How to fix this? GSAP animation for Page transition work perfectly only the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap, barbajs

I`m using barba.js with Gsap.
The idea is to have a transition from the home page and the about page with a centered logo animation, very simple. I click on my button, the transition comes in, the logo scale from 0 to 1, and go down fading, **great!**

The first animation works as it should but when I clicked again the scale factor is now missing, unfortunately.

**How can I fix this to make it work? have a look at my code pen project:**

https://codepen.io/cat999/project/editor/AEeEdg

Here my JS

```
function delay(n) {
    n = n || 2000;
    return new Promise((done) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            done();
        }, n);
    });
}

function pageTransition() {
    var tl = gsap.timeline();


    tl.to(".loading-screen", {
        duration: 1,
        width: "100%",
        left: "0%",
        ease: "Expo.easeInOut",
    });



      tl.to("#svg-1", {
       duration: 1,  opacity: 0,  y: 30, stagger: 0.4, delay: 0.2, 
    });


    tl.to(".loading-screen", {
        duration: 1,
        width: "100%",
        left: "100%",
        ease: "Expo.easeInOut",
        delay: 0.3,
    });

      tl.set(".loading-screen", { left: "-100%", });
      tl.set("#svg-1", { opacity: 1,  y: 0 });
}

function contentAnimation() {
    var tl = gsap.timeline();
    tl.from(".animate-this", { duration: 1, y: 30, opacity: 0, stagger: 0.4, delay: 0.2 });
}

$(function () {
    barba.init({
        sync: true,

        transitions: [
            {
                async leave(data) {
                    const done = this.async();

                    pageTransition();
                    await delay(2000);
                    done();
                },

                async enter(data) {
                    contentAnimation();
                },

                async once(data) {
                    contentAnimation();
                },
            },
        ],
    });
});
```

Comment: This was answered [on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/24193-page-transitions-gsap-animation-work-perfectly-only-the-first-time-how-to-fix-this/)

Comment: Thanks @ZachSaucier. I also ask for another little tip [on the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/24193-page-transitions-gsap-animation-work-perfectly-only-the-first-time-how-to-fix-this/). I'm now following from there. Looking forward to the reply!